# Не отображаются слои

Tags: html, css, photoshop

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такая беда, не отображается BRAVIS и нижняя желтая полоска в html. Слои обьеденяю,сохраняю для веб, и jpg и png, все равно(

Answer (score 1):

вполне могут быть сделаны "скрытыми слоями" 
посмотрите  [здесь](http://psand.ru/sokryitie-i-vidimost-sloev-v-fotoshope/)